# How to test a random generator

Tags: testing, random

I need to test a random number generator which produces numbers randomly. How to make sure the numbers generated are random.

Comment: We have been assaulted by that comic so many times here on SO that I now recognise 221 and don't even have to follow the link :-)

Comment: I simply recognise the domain xkcd.com and that tends to be more foolproof in my experience...

Comment: Much better : http://www.random.org/analysis/dilbert.jpg

Comment: For a string generator I would suggest to add outcomes to a list and check presence. But for numbers you should rely on statics.

Comment: Here is how I test a random string generator: https://github.com/gsscoder/CSharpx/blob/master/tests/CSharpx.Specs/Outcomes/StringUtilSpecs.cs#L30 in C#.

Answer (score 18):

You can only test *statistical* randomness anyway, and that does not prove whether the number sequence is cryptographically strong.  Statistically testing a PRNG requires quite a lot (10 or even 100Gbytes) of the generated bits.

Dieharder is a very good testing suite.

http://www.phy.duke.edu/~rgb/General/dieharder.php

And TestU01 is also well-known.

http://www.iro.umontreal.ca/~simardr/testu01/tu01.html

Answer (score 15):

Use chi-square testing. What language are you using? I can offer a C++ example. Basically

- Place random numbers in buckets (many times).
- The number of buckets minus one is the [degrees of freedom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi-square_distribution).
- Compare the bucket tallies against "expected" tallies, yielding a chi-square result.
- Use a [chi-square calculator](http://www.fourmilab.ch/rpkp/experiments/analysis/chiCalc.html) to see the probability of getting those results.

Comment: You also need to make sure that the buckets are being filled randomly, i.e. not sequentially.

Comment: Yup. And that's where things get harder.

Comment: That's circular proving. If I am trying to find if the random bits are random enough, how do I source any randomness (yet to be measure) to random sample the bits?

Comment: Yeah, I don't know how to verify that the buckets are filled randomly. All I've been able to do is what I describe in my answer (which was good enough).

Answer (score 11):

Here is a detailed explanation of how to start.  The preliminary test for any RNG is the Monobit test used by the NIST which simply counts the number of 1s and 0s.   http://csrc.nist.gov/groups/ST/toolkit/rng/stats_tests.html

A note about testing a Random Number Generator:
We actually don't need too many RNG tests because many "subsume" one another.

That said, described here is a simple effective new **Ordered Frequency Test** for bits.  This test subsumes any frequency test that expects 50-50 because it is more stringent.

Definitions:  t= tosses / trials  b=bins / urns  s=sessions of tosses  n=sets of sessions

Because coin tosses are usually not 50-50, this new test can be utilized with great effectiveness using a pool of 40,000,000 bits.

When coins are flipped 100 times, the expected values are 53.9795 of one and 46.0205 of the other, sometimes more heads, sometimes more tails.  50-50 is not the expected value of the ordered bins, so this test is superior to any frequency test that instead expects 50-50.

Step 1:  Choice of sample size:  100 tosses / bits.

Step 2:  Choice of number of Sessions:  50 sessions is never sufficient, even with huge sample sizes in the millions.  400 is usually enough.  2000 converges well, so 2000 different samples of 100 tosses are used. Minimal gain occurs above 2000.

Expected values for 2000 sessions of 100 tosses:
  50-50  159.1784748  (Notice that 50-50 occurs a mere 7.96% of the time.)
  51-49  312.1146564
  52-48  294.1080416
  53-47  266.362
  54-46  231.8335926
  55-45  193.8971865
  56-44  155.8102392
  57-43  120.2745706
  58-42   89.16907819
  59-41   63.47629295
  60-40   43.37546685
  61-39   28.4429291
  62-38   17.89152
  63-37   10.79171042
  64-36    6.238957586
  65-35    3.455422663
  66-34    1.832421109
  67 or more   1.747439674

The equation to obtain the exact percentages for bins b=2 and tosses t=100 is:
For 100-0, the odds are 1 / (2^99)  = 1 / (2^(t-1)) 
Then, building up from there, 
for 99-1  previous multiplied by 100 (t) divide by 1
for 98-2  previous multiplied  by 99 (t-1) divide by 2
for 97-3  previous multiplied by 98 (t-2) divide by 3
... skip ...
for 51-49  previous multiplied by 52 (t-48) divide by 49
for 50-50  previous multiplied by 51 (t-49) divide by 50, then divide again by 2.

This equation works with any number of tosses.

Step 3:  A chi-square is taken on these 18 values with 17 degrees of freedom giving a resulting p value.

p values above 0.999 are close to perfection. Can an RNG be too close to perfection too often? Yes, being too predictable. Under 0.001 is where definite problems usually occur. One test suite considers 300 zeroes to the right of the decimal as infinitesimally bad and 10-14 in a row as quite bad. Some consider 6 zeroes bad enough to qualify as a definite clear failure. Some, for the sake of safety, consider 1 or 2 zeroes enough and they are in error. So, instead of a single p value for a single set sometimes providing a p value below 0.01 for an excellent RNG, many sets of sessions are taken.

Step 4:  The p values are fed to a 0-1.0 straight line Kolmogorov-Smirnov test.  Different experts recommend the number of inputs to the K-S test to be from 10 to 1000. 100 is not quite enough.  200 is fine.  500 is slightly aggressive.

Here is pseudocode to obtain the K-S maximum difference:

```
Set low := 0;  Set n := 200;  
Set ansForward := 0; Set ansBack := 0;

sort( pval [n] );
for (j := 0; j < n; j := j+1)   
 {  Set Kback := pval [ j ] - low;
    Set low := low +1 / n;    { Ranges from 0 to 1 }
    Set Kforward := low - pval [ j ];  
    if (Kforward > ansForward) Set ansForward := Kforward;
    if (Kback > ansBack) Set ansBack := Kback;
   }
{ Separate analysis can perhaps be made here on ansForward and ansBack.  Someone like Peter Brand might also examine and magnify the bottom 5% and the top 5%. }
if (ansForward > ansBack)
      return ansForward;
else
      return ansBack;   ∎
```

The K-S answer is not a p value and should not exceed 0.115 for 200 p values.  0.03 to 0.08 is normal for a good RNG.  0.115 to 0.13 is suspect.

The K-S test is very simple  It is also quite effective.

Shown above is a superior new Ordered Frequency Test.  Any RNG which fails this test should not be tested further and immediately replaced.  But, what next?

The OFTest does not subsume the LOR test.  Recommended is the Length Of Runs test with sample size 200,000 with 15 degrees of freedom fed into the K-S test 200 times.  (Note that the expected total of the smallest LOR bin for "more than j" is equal to the jth bin.)

And then what?   For many games, these two tests are all you need.  There are a propensity of choices from NIST, Diehard, Dieharder, Crusher. (Note:  The Diehard Overlapping Sums test is both inferior and faulty, not a faithful interpretation of Marsaglia's original Fortran code.)

Results from a few RNGs with n=200.

1. LCG  134775813x + 1 mod 2^31 seed=11111: 
   High bit:  OFT KS:  0.0841  Pass.  LOR KS:  0.04786 Pass.  Monobit of first 200,000:  -189  Pass.
   Bit 16:  OFT KS:  0.5477 Fail.   Monobit of first 200,000:  114  Pass.
   All bits from 0 to 15 fail the OFT, yet pass the Monobit test.
2. The oft maligned LCG Randu: 65539x + 0 mod 2^31 seed=11111:
   High bit:  OFT KS: 0.03567  LOR KS:  0.07709.   Monobit of first 200,000: -165
   Bit 18:  OFT KS: 0.15143  Monobit of first 200,000: +204
   All bits from 0 to 17 fail the OFT.
3. LCG  69069x + 1 mod 2^32 seed=11111: 
   High bit:  OFT KS: 0.05547  LOR KS:  0.0456     Monobit of 200,000: -290
   Bit 17: OFT KS: 0.1467  Monobit of 200,000: -193
   All bits from 0 to 13 fail the OFT.
4. LCG  3141592653x + 2718281829 mod 2^35 seed=11111:
   High bit: OFT KS: 0.02868   LOR KS: 0.06117    Monobit of 200,000:  -69
   Bit 16:  OFT KS: 0.240  Monobit of 200,000:  -13
   All bits from  0 to 15 fail the OFT.
5. LCG  23x + 0  mod 2^27 seed=11111: 
   High bit:  OFT KS:  0.5368  Monobit of 200,000:  -235
   All bits fail the OFT.

Notice that the low bits of any and every LCG should be discarded from the returned result.

A note about 2^35:  This is the minimum period and significance for any RNG because coin flips and craps runs and such things can happen 30 times in a row, but 35 just isn't expected to happen.  A period of 2^32 is insufficient, too small for real life situations.

LWAP

Comment: What do you mean by `LWAP`?

Answer (score 5):

> How to make sure the numbers generated are random.

You can't **make sure**, there is no way to distinguish with certainty any function from a random number generator using a finite number of tests. But you can do [Statistical Analysis](http://www.random.org/analysis/):

> So, if it is impossible to definitively prove randomness, what can we do instead? The pragmatic approach is to take many sequences of random numbers from a given generator and subject them to a battery of statistical tests. As the sequences pass more of the tests, the confidence in the randomness of the numbers increases and so does the confidence in the generator. However, because we expect some sequences to appear nonrandom (like the ten rolls of six on our die), we should expect some of the sequences to fail at least some of the tests. However, if many sequences fail the tests, we should be suspicious. This is also the way you would intuitively test a die to see if it is loaded: Roll it many times, and if you see too many sequences of the same value coming up, you should be suspicious.

See the section on [Charmaine Kenny](http://www.random.org/analysis/#2005)'s study for more details on the tests you could run.

Answer (score 4):

It's a very difficult thing.

You may try [ENT](http://www.fourmilab.ch/random/) from [Fourmilab](http://www.fourmilab.ch/) and compare it with the results against their RNG, [HotBits](http://www.fourmilab.ch/hotbits/). You may also like to review [Random.org](http://www.random.org/).

This also looks interesting: [Diehard tests](http://stat.fsu.edu/pub/diehard/) (I've not worked with it though).

Comment: The Diehard test suite is not maintained anymore and has been outdated by the NIST test suite for random numbers. See http://www.random.org/analysis/#2005.

Comment: +1 to 'it's a very difficult thing'.  Simple one- or two-statistic tests, including some suggested by other respondents, are just not adequate.  In fact, it's such a difficult thing that, unless you are up with the latest research findings (and your question here on SO suggests that you are not) you would probably (ha ha) be better using an existing PRNG than trying to implement your own.  Better, but less fun.

Answer (score 3):

There is a good tool for this puprose: http://www.phy.duke.edu/~rgb/General/dieharder.php

for example you can test build-in urandom

```
cat /dev/random | dieharder -a -g 200
```

Or write your own script that will create a file with random numbers

```
dieharder -a -g 202 -f random.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot ensure the numbers are random simply because random numbers are, well, *random*.

The chances of getting a string of one million consecutive 9's is the same as getting any other specific one-million-long sequence. The one thing you *can* check for is correct distribution over a large sample set. Run a sizeable test and work out the relative occurrences of each possible outcome.

Over a large enough sample, they should be roughly the same.

One other possibility is to test for non-repeatability. Ideally, random numbers should not depend on the numbers that came before. Very simple (linear congruential) PRNGs will most likely give you the same sequence of numbers eventually but over a large enough set that you probably won't care (unless you're *serious* about randomness).

Answer (score 2):

It depends how severe your requirement for randomness is. If it is not too severe, what I do is generate a large number of random numbers, find their frequencies and then use the frequencies to plot a graph using a spreadshhet like that in Open Office. If the distribution looks OK, then I'm good to go.

Answer (score 1):

Create a log file which will contains the random number for atleast 500 instances and audit it for randomness. Also have a look at below link,

http://burtleburtle.net/bob/rand/testsfor.html

Answer (score 0):

Often if you have your generator draw dots at random locations in a bitmap, any nonrandomness will easily be discernable to the eye as clumping, banding or lines.

Comment: Not sure - I'd be interested to see whether taking a complex but non-random source of data and plotting it on an xy bitmap might still "look" random.

Comment: Jeffrey is exactly right -- the "looks random plotted" test is a necessary but not sufficient test for randomness of a signal.

Comment: Down vote because random does not mean not clumpy. Just because something is random doesn't mean it is evenly distributed. Humans are also prone to recognize patterns even if they don't really exist. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gambler's_fallacy or http://theness.com/neurologicablog/index.php/data-mining-adventures-in-pattern-recognition/

Answer (score 0):

You can't generate true randomness by any algorithm, thus try to visualize your outputs and check for patterns with your own eyes. None random generator (by algorithm) would create some patterns that you can judge them yourself. Here is one of demonstration of that idea: http://www.alife.co.uk/nonrandom/

Comment: Down vote because random does not mean non pattern. Humans are prone to recognize patterns even if they don't really exist. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gambler's_fallacy or http://theness.com/neurologicablog/index.php/data-mining-adventures-in-pattern-recognition/

Comment: I really don't know what you mean by "random does not mean non pattern"? Do you mean that "random" would create "pattern"? True randomness or "randomness by algorithm"? Don't you read my answer?! Lol!

Comment: Random data can look like it has a pattern even if it doesn't. For example, perfectly random data often looks clumpier than people expect because they expect random to mean evenly distributed.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have access to the random number generator and can use it to generate numbers at will, you *can't* test if a sequence of numbers is random.  Think about it: you have a random number generator.  Let's say it's a uniform random number generator, generating random integers in the range [0,9].  Given a sequence:

```
0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9
```

can you tell if it is random?  There is a finite probability 10<sup>−10</sup>, that our uniform random number generator will generate this exact sequence.  In fact, given *any* length-10 sequence, we have the same probability of our uniform random number generator generating that sequence.  Hence, by definition, you can't determine if a given sequence is random.

If you do have access to the generator itself, and can use it to generate multiple sequences, then it makes sense to "check for randomness".   For this, I would look at [Diehard tests](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diehard_tests).  There are various implementations.

Comment: Why wouldn't you have access to the PRNG you want to test? All the randomness tests make, of course, heavy use of the PRNG they are testing, and performs various tests on long sequences of generated numbers, like the DieHard tests you cite.