# Matlab : Is the calculation of variance correct?

Tags: matlab, signal-processing, variance

I am generating PRBS values taking values in `[+1,-1]` as

`data = 2*(rand(100,1)>0.5)-1`

I want to get the variance of the output and so used `variance_data = var(data)`

Would `var()` be applicable to PRBS or data taking symbols such as `[+3,-3,+7,-7,+5,-5]` etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `var` function works for any population, including your array of 1s and -1s.

But I'll take a wild guess that this is not what you want. Variance is only a measure of how the data spreads out of the mean. A true random generator of 1s and -1s would have a variance of 1. So if you use `var`, all you get is to approximate the result to 1 as you generate longer and longer sequences.

If you want to check if your random generator is good, this might help you:

[How to test a random generator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2130621/how-to-test-a-random-generator)

For any other purposes, you probably can use `var` on your sequence.